# html checkbox gets clicked when it shouldn't

Tags: html, checkbox

I have a table with three columns. One with an input text box and the two others with an input checkbox. So :

```
inputText - inputCheckbox - inputCheckBox
inputText - inputCheckbox - inputCheckBox
inputText - inputCheckbox - inputCheckBox
inputText - inputCheckbox - inputCheckBox
```

When I click anywhere on the table, the first checkbox change his value.
this is incomprehensible.

Any clue ?

Even if jquery is included in the page, no javascript is linked to this table and controls.

Finaly I could isolate the code : [jsfiddle.net/P86du](http://jsfiddle.net/P86du)

Comment: Real source code in flavor of an SSCCE or a jsfiddle.net demo would be more helpful for us to help you.

Comment: Something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/9nu4z/6/)?  Seems to be OK in latest version of Chrome.

Comment: Firefox 4. I didn't put the code because it's embedded in a big page and the table is coming from an ajax request...

Comment: Finaly I could bring out a code : http://jsfiddle.net/P86du/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is you have an unclosed `<label>` tag. Clicking on a label will check the associated box.

Without seeing the source, we won't know for sure.

Comment: You were right : see http://jsfiddle.net/P86du/2/ so How to have checkbox in a label tag

Comment: You generally want the checkbox outside of the label tag, and use the `for` attribute of the label to refer to the checkbox's `id`.

Answer (score 0):

With *plain* HTML this should never happen- do you have addons in your browser that might interfere?

Are there any source code snippets "onXXX" (e.g. onClick, onBlur, ...)?
Are there any script-tags?

A link to your html-source might be handy.